# AutoCompleteTextView как скрыть список при установке текста

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Здравствуйте.

Есть разметка:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_s1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
    app:counterTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MyTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_sCity"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewGPS">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText_nameStreet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:hint="Улица откуда поедете"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWorning" />

    <requestFocus />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Есть заполнение выпадающего списка улицами для `editText_nameStreet`.

Как только делаю `editTextNameStreet.setText("Московский проспект");` так сразу появляется выпадающий список, с "Московский проспект".

*Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать этот список во время присвоения? Т.е. выпадающий список нужен, но при присвоении его отображать не надо*

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать так

```
editTextNameStreet.setText("");
editTextNameStreet.append(GlobalValue.myOrder.getStreet()); //добавление текста
editTextHome.requestFocus(); //смена фокуса на другой элемент
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод dismissDropDown()

```
editTextNameStreet.dismissDropDown();
```